# Emacs shortcut combination used by workgroups2 's-/'

Tags: emacs, shortcut

In the [workgroups2](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2) package, an example shortcut is defined as :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-/")  'wg-switch-to-previous-workgroup)
```

How would one invoke the 's-/' shortcut?

Comment: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

Comment: Ah, so in this case s is super. Wasn't easy to google for.. Thanks. Happy to accept if you post as an answer

Comment: I recommend learning to use the in-built manuals. A regexp isearch through the elisp manual for `\bs-` gives you the answer very quickly indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s-/` stands for <kbd>Super + /</kbd>. If you don't have a Space-cadet keyboard, there's a chance it's already mapped to some other key (or can be remapped to it) as described here:

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

You can also define your own shortcuts using different keys.

Comment: For me, super was already mapped to the windows key on my microsoft keyboard.